# Как составить регулярку для формата +7 (9xx) xx-xx-xx?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Формат нужен такой: `+7 (9xx) xx-xx-xx`

где `x` - любое число от 0 до 9. Пробелы и скобки должны обязательно соблюдаться.

Сделал такое:

```
/^\+7\s(9[0-9]{2})\s[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/
```

В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что скобка (равно как и плюс) является метасимволом и точно так же требует экранирования:

```
/^\+7\s\(9[0-9]{2}\)\s[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/
```

данная регулярка успешно отрабатывает в js:

```
/^\+7\s\(9[0-9]{2}\)\s[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/.test('+7 (999) 77-77-77')
```

Comment: Есть же добрые люди, спасибо :)